# Transformation with multiple document context

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, document

I have an xsl which uses external documents. The xsl contains xsl:key element and this is not working properly when external document is being used.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:param name="People"></xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="Abstracts"></xsl:param>
  <xsl:key name="uniqueAfflTags" match="AFFL" use="concat(../../../../@id,@number)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="abstracts" select="document($Abstracts)//ABSTRACT"/>

<!--Root template -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//PRESENTATIONS/PRESENTATION[@type!='placeholder']">
          <xsl:sort select="AUTHORS/AUTHOR[1]/LNAME"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PRESENTATION">
    <xsl:variable name="ctrlid" select="@control_id"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <!--  Category -->
    <xsl:if test="string-length($abstracts[@id=$ctrlid]/ABSTRACT_CATEGORY/CATEGORY_GROUP/CATEGORY) &gt; 0">
      <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
      <span class="Category">
        <xsl:value-of select="$abstracts[@id=$ctrlid]/ABSTRACT_CATEGORY/CATEGORY_GROUP/CATEGORY"/>
      </span>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::AFFL">
      <xsl:sort select="@number" data-type="number"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AFFL">
    <xsl:if test="generate-id()=generate-id(key('uniqueAfflTags',concat(../../../../@id,@number))[1])">
      (<xsl:value-of select="@number"/>)
      <xsl:if test="string-length(DEPT) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="DEPT"/>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test="string-length(INST) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:if test="string-length(DEPT) &gt; 0">
          <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="INST"/>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test="string-length(CITY) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:if test="string-length(INST) &gt; 0 or string-length(DEPT) &gt; 0">
          <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="CITY"/>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test="string-length(STATE) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:if test="string-length(CITY) &gt; 0 or string-length(INST) &gt; 0 or string-length(DEPT) &gt; 0">
          <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="STATE"/>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test="string-length(COUNTRY) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:if test="COUNTRY!='United States'">
          <xsl:if test="string-length(STATE) &gt; 0 or string-length(CITY) &gt; 0 or string-length(INST) &gt; 0 or string-length(DEPT) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:value-of select="COUNTRY"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with current xsl, the if condition in AFFL template match is not satisfying. If I remove the lines:

```
<xsl:variable name="ctrlid" select="@control_id"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <!--  Category -->
    <xsl:if test="string-length($abstracts[@id=$ctrlid]/ABSTRACT_CATEGORY/CATEGORY_GROUP/CATEGORY) &gt; 0">
      <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
      <span class="Category">
        <xsl:value-of select="$abstracts[@id=$ctrlid]/ABSTRACT_CATEGORY/CATEGORY_GROUP/CATEGORY"/>
      </span>
    </xsl:if>
```

it starts working. The problem looks like of the incorrect context but I am not able to set the context properly.
Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks

Input xml -> primary xml (session)

```
<PRESENTATION id="1424043" sess_sort="10" control_id="1841983" type="abstract">
          <FINAL_ID><![CDATA[]]></FINAL_ID>
          <DURATION><![CDATA[20]]></DURATION>
          <PRESENTATION_START_TIME>
            <HOUR><![CDATA[04]]></HOUR>
            <MINUTE><![CDATA[05]]></MINUTE>
            <AM_PM><![CDATA[PM]]></AM_PM>
          </PRESENTATION_START_TIME>
          <PRESENTATION_END_TIME>
            <HOUR><![CDATA[04]]></HOUR>
            <MINUTE><![CDATA[25]]></MINUTE>
            <AM_PM><![CDATA[PM]]></AM_PM>
          </PRESENTATION_END_TIME>
          <TITLE><![CDATA[Rift Structures in the Angola Margin: Block 0]]></TITLE>
          <STATUS><![CDATA[Sessioned]]></STATUS>
          <DECISION_STATUS><![CDATA[Accept]]></DECISION_STATUS>
          <DESC><![CDATA[]]></DESC>
          <USER_DEFINED_1><![CDATA[false]]></USER_DEFINED_1>
          <AUTHORS>
            <AUTHOR order="1" person_id="2720052" presenter="true">
              <FNAME><![CDATA[Li-Fan]]></FNAME>
              <MNAME><![CDATA[]]></MNAME>
              <LNAME><![CDATA[Yue]]></LNAME>
              <AFFILIATIONS>
                <AFFL author_order="1" number="1">
                  <DEPT><![CDATA[]]></DEPT>
                  <INST><![CDATA[Chevron]]></INST>
                  <CITY><![CDATA[Houston]]></CITY>
                  <STATE><![CDATA[Texas]]></STATE>
                  <COUNTRY><![CDATA[United States]]></COUNTRY>
                </AFFL>
              </AFFILIATIONS>
            </AUTHOR>
            <AUTHOR order="2" person_id="2713558" presenter="false">
              <FNAME><![CDATA[Chris]]></FNAME>
              <MNAME><![CDATA[]]></MNAME>
              <LNAME><![CDATA[Guzofski]]></LNAME>
              <AFFILIATIONS>
                <AFFL author_order="1" number="1">
                  <DEPT><![CDATA[]]></DEPT>
                  <INST><![CDATA[Chevron]]></INST>
                  <CITY><![CDATA[Houston]]></CITY>
                  <STATE><![CDATA[Texas]]></STATE>
                  <COUNTRY><![CDATA[United States]]></COUNTRY>
                </AFFL>
              </AFFILIATIONS>
            </AUTHOR>
          </AUTHORS>
          <BODY>
            <SECTION part_of_body="1">
              <SECTION_NAME bold="true" italic="false" underline="false" name_appears="false"><![CDATA[Abstract Body]]></SECTION_NAME>
              <TEXT><![CDATA[
Angola Block 0 has long been a prolific asset for Angola and Chevron ever since the Cabinda Gulf Oil Company drilled the first well in the late 
]]></TEXT>
            </SECTION>
          </BODY>
        </PRESENTATION>
```

Second xml (Abstract XML)--

```
<ABSTRACT id="1785505">
      <STATUS><![CDATA[Sessioned]]></STATUS>
      <DECISION_STATUS><![CDATA[Accept]]></DECISION_STATUS>
      <TITLE><![CDATA[Fault controlled extension regime– a case of the Albertine Graben - East African Rift System, Uganda]]></TITLE>
      <PRESENTATION_TYPE><![CDATA[Oral Only]]></PRESENTATION_TYPE>
      <ABSTRACT_CATEGORY>
        <CATEGORY_GROUP>
          <CATEGORY category_id="136962"><![CDATA[Theme 8: Structure, Tectonics, and Geomechanics]]></CATEGORY>
          <SUB_CATEGORY sub_category_id="137018"><![CDATA[3. Structure and Geodynamics of Extensional Margins and Impact on the Evolution of Petroleum Systems and Reservoir Productivity]]></SUB_CATEGORY>
        </CATEGORY_GROUP>
      </ABSTRACT_CATEGORY>
      <AUTHORS>
        <AUTHOR order="1" person_id="2646796" presenter="true">
          <SAL><![CDATA[Mr.]]></SAL>
          <FNAME><![CDATA[Dozith]]></FNAME>
          <MNAME><![CDATA[]]></MNAME>
          <LNAME><![CDATA[Abeinomugisha]]></LNAME>
          <DEGREE><![CDATA[Msc Petroleum Geoscience]]></DEGREE>
          <EMAIL><![CDATA[d.abeinomugisha@petroleum.go.ug]]></EMAIL>
          <ADDRESS_1><![CDATA[Plot 21-29, End of Johnstone road, Entebbe]]></ADDRESS_1>
          <ADDRESS_2><![CDATA[]]></ADDRESS_2>
          <CITY><![CDATA[Entebbe]]></CITY>
          <STATE><![CDATA[]]></STATE>
          <POSTAL_CODE><![CDATA[9]]></POSTAL_CODE>
          <COUNTRY><![CDATA[Uganda]]></COUNTRY>
          <PHONE><![CDATA[+256414320714]]></PHONE>
          <FAX><![CDATA[+256414320437]]></FAX>
          <AFFILIATIONS>
            <AFFL author_order="1" number="1">
              <DEPT><![CDATA[Geology]]></DEPT>
              <INST><![CDATA[Petroleum Exploration and Production Department]]></INST>
              <CITY><![CDATA[Entebbe]]></CITY>
              <STATE><![CDATA[]]></STATE>
              <COUNTRY><![CDATA[Uganda]]></COUNTRY>
            </AFFL>
          </AFFILIATIONS>
        </AUTHOR>
      </AUTHORS>
      <BODY>
        <SECTION part_of_body="1">
          <SECTION_NAME bold="false" italic="false" underline="false" name_appears="false"><![CDATA[Abstract Body]]></SECTION_NAME>
          <TEXT><![CDATA[The Albertine graben forms the northernmost termination of the western arm of the East African Rift System. Rifting was initiated.
]]></TEXT>
        </SECTION>
      </BODY>
    </ABSTRACT>
```

If it is really a context issue then how should I select the context for the base document.

Comment: Can I ask for your input XML, and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

The key index is built per document and the key function works on the document of the current context node so generally with multiple documents you need to make sure you change the context with e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="some-key-value" select="foo"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$otherDoc">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('key-name', $some-key-value)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

in XSLT 1.0 or with XSLT 2.0 you can shorten that to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('key-name', foo, $otherDoc)"/>
```

If you need more concrete help then please show us the structure of your input documents.

Comment: I have two XMLs, one is session on which this xsl is being applied and other one is abstract xml which I am using through document. The template match for AFFL tab should be for current context which is session as the xsl is applied on this. I need to get the unique affl info ind this context which is the session xml but its not happening. I'll update the question with relevant section of input xml.

Comment: I found one more thing that generate-id does not work the way u want if you are using it with key and multiple document contexts.